# IIS control on windows Azure

Tags: .net, windows, iis, azure

I understand that one can host multiple websites on windows azure, I would like to know if I can add more websites to my cloud solution after I have already deployed it. If I am unable to would you have to add another site to the project then redeploy or it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your sites in your service definition file.  You can add sites to your service definition file and either redeploy your application tiers or do a VIP swap update.  With the latter, you won't miss a beat - you can deploy new roles in the staging slot (which will use the new config with the new sites) and then swap the staging and production slots. Requests will drain off the old and new requests redirected to the new.  Voila, you're new site is live.

That's how we update our services (which we recently just added a new site as well).

Here's more info on IIS service definition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433059.aspx

Here's more info on VIP swap:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee517253.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I would also like to ask how the hostnames are handled in this circumstance, would I be able to have multiple host names?

Comment: In our specific case, we had different services on different ports.  but, if you wanted a different DNS host name to resolve to the two different sites, look at the bindings section.  There's a concept called host headers.  If both are on the same port & IP (VIP) then host header is a way to disambiguate.  If name in header is somehost.site.com then route to this site.  etc...

Comment: Note that I have tried host headers and IIS in traditional deployments but not in Azure.  I don't see why it wouldn't work because it's just full IIS on a VM in the cloud ...

Comment: Thanks bryan, I'm not completely polished in my knowledge here I would like to try and understand how this works. You use a CNAME with your dns provider to point to your windows azure Service? so does the original host actually come in the HTTP message or the .cloudapp is the one in the message? I apologise I never quite understood the bit with hosts.

Comment: Your DNS provider would create a CNAME (alias) for the name @ cloud app.  Then when someone requests somehost.yoursite.com, it's an alias for your cloudapp DNS name (which actually resolves to the virtual IP for your cluster provisioned and managed by Azure).

Comment: Send me a mail on my contact info and I can follow up and ping some folks if needed ...